# searching files in a site and copy them to an array

Tags: php, arrays, full-text-search

I want to search *.rules from this site http://cvs.snort.org/viewcvs.cgi/snort/rules/

and copy the strings of files into an array

how can I do this?
for example:

```
$array=array('backdoor.rules','bad-traffic.rules');
```

I can use

```
$str=file_get_contents( 'http://cvs.snort.org/viewcvs.cgi/snort/rules');
```

but how can I search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a regex to get any matches of the source

```
    $url = 'http://cvs.snort.org/viewcvs.cgi/snort/rules/';
    $contents = file_get_contents($url);
    //Regex to match any links that have .rule in it
    preg_match_all('/<a href="([^"]+\.rules[^"]*)">/i', $contents, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    foreach ($result[1] as $link) {
        //Fetch the link and save
    }
```

This code will fetch the contents of the web page, and run a regex which matches any link that has .rules in it.

Inside the loop you can then save the files (using file_get_contents , and then [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fwrite](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) and [fclose](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php))

Comment: $result[1] is an array of all of the matches, if there was just one match you could, but that variable is pretty much this - `$result[1] = array('/test.rules','/more.rules');` so we have to loop over it

Comment: I used this one `echo $result[1][0];` here is the result:`attack-responses.rules?rev=1.35&content-type=text/vnd.viewcvs-mark....`

Comment: can't we do the thing that exactly return us attack-responses.rules?

Comment: $results[1] is pretty much identical to the array you mentioned in your post, `$array=array('backdoor.rules','bad-traffic.rules');`, so you could do `$array = $results[1]` and it would be the same

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the contents

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://cvs.snort.org/viewcvs.cgi/snort/rules/');
```

2. Search and put the found files in `$matches[1]`

```
preg_match_all('/href="([^"]+\.rules)"/', $contents, $matches);
```

3. Do anything with the array

```
$matches[1];
```